# Reference main object variable in C#

Tags: c#, json.net, hierarchy

I have an object which populates through custom `JsonConverter`. It has another object inside whom I want to pass/share a main object property.

**Weather.cs**

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonPathConverter))]
public class Weather
{
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "timezone_offset")]
    public int TimezoneOffset { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "current")]
    public Current Current { get; set; }
}
```

**Current**

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonPathConverter))]
public class Current
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dt")]
    public int Timestamp { get; set; }

    public string FormattedDate()
    {
        string response = string.Empty;

        // Here's where I want to access TimezoneOffset

        return response;
    }

    // More stuff...
}
```

**JsonPathConverter**

```
public class JsonPathConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        object targetObj = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in objectType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite))
        {
            JsonPropertyAttribute att = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                                            .OfType<JsonPropertyAttribute>()
                                            .FirstOrDefault();

            string jsonPath = (att != null ? att.PropertyName : prop.Name);
            JToken token = jo.SelectToken(jsonPath);

            if (token != null && token.Type != JTokenType.Null)
            {
                object value = token.ToObject(prop.PropertyType, serializer);
                prop.SetValue(targetObj, value, null);
            }
        }

        return targetObj;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value.GetType().IsGenericType && value is IEnumerable)
        {
            JArray result = new JArray();
            IEnumerable list = value as IEnumerable;

            foreach(var obj in list)
                result.Add(GetObjectJson(obj));

            result.WriteTo(writer);
        }
        else
        {
            JObject result = GetObjectJson(value);
            result.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }

    private JObject GetObjectJson(object obj)
    {
        JObject jObj = new JObject();

        if (obj != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
            {
                if (prop.PropertyType.ToString().Contains("System") || prop.PropertyType.ToString().Contains("Json"))
                    jObj.Add(char.ToLowerInvariant(prop.Name[0]) + prop.Name.Substring(1), JToken.FromObject(prop.GetValue(obj)));
                else
                    jObj.Add(char.ToLowerInvariant(prop.Name[0]) + prop.Name.Substring(1), GetObjectJson(prop.GetValue(obj)));
            }
        }

        return jObj;
    }
}
```

I've tried using hierarchy, but it creates an empty Current object when it serializes the JSON.

**UPDATE**

To be more clear, here's an example of how I use this:

I make an `HttpRequest` which returns a JSON like this:

```
{
    "timezone_offset": 7200,
    "current": {
        "dt": 1600242501,
        "sunrise": 1600234796,
        "sunset": 1600279440,
        "temp": 24.85,
        "feels_like": 26.84,
        "pressure": 1019,
        "humidity": 78,
        "dew_point": 20.75,
        "uvi": 7.42,
        "clouds": 2,
        "visibility": 10000,
        "wind_speed": 2.96,
        "wind_deg": 66,
        "weather": [{
            "id": 800,
            "main": "Clear",
            "description": "cielo claro",
            "icon": "01d"
        }]
    }
}
```

Then, I deserialize it into the `Weather` object:

```
Weather weather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Weather>(json.ToString());
```

It populates both `Weather` and `Current` objects, since `Current` object is a property of `Weather` itself.

Then, when I want to return the `Weather` object I do it like this:

```
JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(weather, Formatting.Indented, new JsonPathConverter()))
```

In that moment I want to return a new field `FormattedDate` in `Current` object which is calculated. I've done this before and it works, the problem now is that I want it to use the parent property `TimezoneOffset` in this field.

Comment: Why and how do you want to "access" TimezoneOffset?

Comment: @Fildor well, I want to return a string with formatted date. Since it could be a date from anywhere, I have to apply offset in order to get correct datetime.

Comment: @Sinatr I'm not sure what are you telling me.

Comment: @JohnG `Weather` has a `Current` object property, what I want is to use `Weather.TimezoneOffset` inside that `Current` property.

Comment: You are adding *method* in DTO and according to edit it should be a *property*. Simply deserialize `Weather`, assign a new value to new property and serialize. You don't need references or converters.